# Django User ID fields

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am creating a new User object using the following code:

```
user = User(username=new_data['username'], email=new_data['email'], first_name=new_data['email'])
user.save()
user_id = user.id
```

Now, I need to retrieve the id of the user into a variable called user_id. However, when I do this, user_id has the value of "Nothing". When I look in the database, however, I can see the newly created user entry in the database.

How can I get the id of the user record?

Comment: This *should* work. Can you try it again with a fresh session, and copy/paste the full output here?

Comment: Here is what I ended up having to do:

    user = User.objects.create_user(username=new_data['username'], email=new_data['email'])
    user.set_password(new_data['password'])
    user.first_name = new_data['first_name']
    user.userid = user.pk
    user_id = user.pk
    user.save()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a User, you could try the following:

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username=new_data['username'], email=new_data['email'])
print user.pk #Already works as create_user saves the new instance.
user.first_name = new_data['email'] #Can't assign to first_name in create_user.
user.save()
print user.pk #Will work.
```

By the way, this also normalizes the e-mail address & all.

If you need to assign other parameters, such as first name, just use your user variable, assign to these values and then save.

You should read up about Model managers if you want more information on this.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot, except it didn't work. I had to change it slightly. The solution was:
user = User.objects.create_user(...

Comment: Yep, sure, sorry if I didn't write that, must have been kinda away when I wrote this! Glad it helped : )

Answer (score 5):

Try

`user_id = user.pk`

instead of

`user_id = user.id`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that seems to have the exact same result.

Comment: You helped me dude.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specific to django, but check out SQLAlchemy's handling of `PostgreSQL`'s `RETURNING`:

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/dialects/postgresql.html#insert-update-returning

I don't know how you'd coerce Django's ORM to make use of that, but SQLA's making use of pscopg2 to get `RETURNING` support.